# How to plot small bar in combination with long bars?

Tags: pgfplots

The first bar in all groups is not visible. How to make it visible?

Here is MWE which is not working.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1in, right=1in, top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11, width=10cm, height=7cm,
    /pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \draw [#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);},
    },
}

\begin{document}


\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{

    workload,       EMRSAY,     L-BOUND,    L-MSPAN
    {128M,64R},     0.004,      0.4,        0.4
    {128M,128R},    0.005,      0.6,        0.6
    {256M,64R},     0.006,      0.8,        0.8
    {256M,128R},    0.007,      0.8,        0.8
    {256M,256R},    0.007,      1.0,        1.0
    {512M,128R},    0.008,      1.0,        1.0
    {512M,256R},    0.008,      1.1,        1.1
    {512M,512R},    0.009,      1.4,        1.4

}\PageRankb

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=.80,xscale=.80]

\begin{axis}[
%x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
ybar,
cycle list={{fill=white, postaction={pattern=crosshatch}}, {fill=gray, postaction={pattern=north east lines}}, {fill=white, postaction={pattern=crosshatch dots}}},
ymin=0.001, ymax=2,
ytick={0.001,0.01,0.1,1},
bar width=0.15cm, %width=1\textwidth,
enlarge x limits=0.15,
enlarge y limits={.45, upper},
legend style={at={(1,1)}, anchor=north east, legend columns=1},
xlabel={Workload},
ylabel={Execution time (s)},
xticklabels from table={\PageRankb}{workload},
xtick=data,
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
%nodes near coords,%vaule of data over the bar
%nodes near coords align={vertical}
]

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {1,...,3}{
    \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y index=#1] {\PageRankb};
}
\legend{1st, 2nd, 3rd}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want a bar chart similar to following with same yticks:

[image]

Comment: Add `ymode=log,log origin=infty,` after `year,` to have a logarithmic plot.

Comment: Freaky autocorrection. I wanted to say "Add `ymode=log,log origin=infty,` after `ybar,` to have a logarithmic plot." The reason is that there are two orders of magnitude between the heights of the bars, which means that it will be hard to make the small ones very visible on a linear scale.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I followed your suggestion. Although I got all the bars in each group, the values of yticks are now showing in power of tens. Can I have orginal yticks?

Comment: How about `ymode=log,log origin=infty,log ticks with fixed point,`?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Got following error: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/log ticks with fixed point misspelled it. \end{axis}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is a large hierarchy in the heights of the bars, you may want to use a logarithmic plot. The tick labels and ticks can be controlled by adjusting keys.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1in, right=1in, top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11, width=10cm, height=7cm,
    /pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \draw [#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);},
    },
}

\begin{document}


\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{

    workload,       EMRSAY,     L-BOUND,    L-MSPAN
    {128M,64R},     0.004,      0.4,        0.4
    {128M,128R},    0.005,      0.6,        0.6
    {256M,64R},     0.006,      0.8,        0.8
    {256M,128R},    0.007,      0.8,        0.8
    {256M,256R},    0.007,      1.0,        1.0
    {512M,128R},    0.008,      1.0,        1.0
    {512M,256R},    0.008,      1.1,        1.1
    {512M,512R},    0.009,      1.4,        1.4

}\PageRankb

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=.80,xscale=.80]

\begin{axis}[ybar,ymode=log,log origin=infty,log ticks with fixed point,
cycle list={{fill=white, postaction={pattern=crosshatch}}, {fill=gray, postaction={pattern=north east lines}}, {fill=white, postaction={pattern=crosshatch dots}}},
ymin=0.001, ymax=2,
ytick={0.001,0.01,0.1,1},
bar width=0.15cm, %width=1\textwidth,
enlarge x limits=0.15,
enlarge y limits={.45, upper},
legend style={at={(1,1)}, anchor=north east, legend columns=1},
xlabel={Workload},
ylabel={Execution time (s)},
xticklabels from table={\PageRankb}{workload},
xtick=data,
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east}]

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {1,...,3}{
    \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y index=#1] {\PageRankb};
}
\legend{1st, 2nd, 3rd}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without drawing the y ticks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1in, right=1in, top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11, width=10cm, height=7cm,
    /pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \draw [#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);},
    },
}

\begin{document}


\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{

    workload,       EMRSAY,     L-BOUND,    L-MSPAN
    {128M,64R},     0.004,      0.4,        0.4
    {128M,128R},    0.005,      0.6,        0.6
    {256M,64R},     0.006,      0.8,        0.8
    {256M,128R},    0.007,      0.8,        0.8
    {256M,256R},    0.007,      1.0,        1.0
    {512M,128R},    0.008,      1.0,        1.0
    {512M,256R},    0.008,      1.1,        1.1
    {512M,512R},    0.009,      1.4,        1.4

}\PageRankb

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=.80,xscale=.80]

\begin{axis}[ybar,ymode=log,log origin=infty,log ticks with fixed point,
ytick style={draw=none},
cycle list={{fill=white, postaction={pattern=crosshatch}}, {fill=gray, postaction={pattern=north east lines}}, {fill=white, postaction={pattern=crosshatch dots}}},
ymin=0.001, ymax=2,
ytick={0.001,0.01,0.1,1},
bar width=0.15cm, %width=1\textwidth,
enlarge x limits=0.15,
enlarge y limits={.45, upper},
legend style={at={(1,1)}, anchor=north east, legend columns=1},
xlabel={Workload},
ylabel={Execution time (s)},
xticklabels from table={\PageRankb}{workload},
xtick=data,
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east}]

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {1,...,3}{
    \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y index=#1] {\PageRankb};
}
\legend{1st, 2nd, 3rd}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: one last thing. How to remove tiny horizontal lines on the y-axis?

Comment: @user3606704 Do you mean the ticks? If so, add `ytick style={draw=none},`.

Comment: Thanks!!.......